# how create char dataset like minst_digits dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pattern-recognition

I have 62000 font images( 0-9,A-Z and a-z images) data set in which for single character have  1000 image.I have created csv file of 62000 row of images normalized pixel value and labels. I don't know to extract this csv file in training,validation and testing dataset so that i can get better accuracy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw98z.png)

Comment: Work on your formatting, also, perhaps you want to use https://keras.io/datasets/ or http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#introduction ? Many machine-learning platforms have some easy loading of mnist available.

Comment: these dataset is for digits only. i want to train on character dataset. i have dataset but i am confusing how to make it more simple for training, validation and testing. dataset of CSV file i have in which 1000 images of 'A',1000 images of 'B' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SciKit-Learn's `train_test_split`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = your.data, your.target #input your own data here
train, test = train_test_split(X, test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)
```

Also, read this sklearn [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html)